# how to avoid java.sql.SQLException:[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] could not find file '(unkown)'

Tags: java, sql, windows-7, odbc, 32bit-64bit

Im on java se and microsoft access /jet database on windows 7. Prior to using windows 7, i used win xp. Used eclipse to write the code, build the database on ms access 2007 and used the odbc - system dsn to establish connection. On win xp, my database connection works fine and my navigation controls on java seems perfect but on windows 7 it prompts an error:

```
java.sql.SQLException:[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] could not find file '(unknown)'.
```

I already added the 32 bit odbc on `c:windows\syswow64` and established the connection in administrative tools/odbc but still prompts me with that error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add to Microsoft Access Driver in administrative tools.

If that doesn't work do :

```
try
{
  //your code
} 
catch(Exception ex)
{

}
```

this is my code:

```
public void dbconnect1(){
    try{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    condb1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Datab1");
    stdb1 = condb1.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    String sql = "Select * from Table1";
    rsdb1 = stdb1.executeQuery(sql);

    if (rsdb1.next()){
    textid.setText(rsdb1.getString("id"));
    textfn.setText(rsdb1.getString("fn"));
    textln.setText(rsdb1.getString("ln"));
    textdep.setText(rsdb1.getString("dept"));
    textpos.setText(rsdb1.getString("position"));
    textyearh.setText(rsdb1.getString("yearhired"));

    } else {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"connection in charge");}


    } catch (Exception ex){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"error connect"+ex);}

}
```

Comment: Have you printed your exception errors? If so what do they say?